# Array formula check multiple columns in row against list and vlookup the match

Tags: excel, formula

I have a set of ID columns, which contains 0-1 of the IDs that are in my lookup list. I want to find that unique ID and then vlookup against another  table. E.g.

In a given row, A-F have IDs, D has the unique ID that is in the separate table. D corresponds to "XXXXX" so we return that in G.

I realize this has to likely use array formulas but I am not sure where to start.

```
| A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
-----------------------------
| - | - | - | X | - | - | ? |
```

```
| ID | Lookup |
---------------
| A  |  AAAAA |
|... |  ..... |
| X  |  XXXXX |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if the value in D is truely unique and the other values are not in your lookup list than:

[image]

Formula translates to:

```
=INDEX(J2:J7,SUMPRODUCT((A2:F2=I2:I7)*ROW(I2:I7))-1)
```